# ¿Puede crearse AssetDatabase desde el cliente o solo desde el editor?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tenía la duda de si en el cliente de Unity3D se podría crear `AssetDatabase` en runtime o siempre hay que dejarlas creadas en el editor antes de compilar.

Answer (score 1):

Los métodos de AssetDatabase sólo te funcionarán en el editor. Durante la ejecución del programa puedes usar [Resources o AssetBundles](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/guide-assetbundles-and-resources).

Comment: Gracias , entonces hay que crearlas y luego usarlas por defecto.